# how to format a column in pandas using a column name

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I want to format a column in a dataframe to have ',' between large numbers once i send the df to_excel. i have a code that works but it selects the column based on its position. I want a code to select the column based on its name and not position. can someone help me please?

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Final Trade List')

wb = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['Final Trade List']

format = wb.add_format({'num_format': '#,##'})

ws.set_column('O:O', 12, format) # this code works but its based on position and not name

ws.set_column(df['$ to buy'], 12, format) # this gives me an error

writer.save()

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
df['columnname'] = pd.Series([format(val, ',') for val in df['columnname']], index = df.index)
```